# What does the # character mean in: /bin/sed -e 's#abc#zzz#g'?

Tags: command-line, sed

What does the `#` character mean in this line:

```
/bin/sed -e 's#abc#zzz#g'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a separator, just like `"/"`, it's same as `'s/abc/zzz/g'`.

it means search for "abc" replace it with "zzz", with global flag, means do it for all "abc"s on the line, not just the first one.

You can also use an alternative separator for a pattern address, but in that case, you need to escape it for it to be correctly interpreted:

```
sed -r '\#abc#p'
```

Answer (score 24):

It's a *delimiter* or separator. The most commonly used one is `/` as in

```
sed 's/old/new/' file
```

But sed will take the first character after the command (s) as delimiter. You can use any convenient character, for example...

```
sed 's%old%new%' file
```

This is very useful if the file contains `/` (or other conventional delimiting characters). You can choose as separator some character that you know you won't need to put into your `sed` expression, saving you a lot of annoying escaping.

Let's say you want to replace

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions
```

with

```
https://askubuntu.com/posts
```

You could use

```
sed 's/https:\/\/askubuntu.com\/questions/https:\/\/askubuntu.com\/posts/' file
```

But better to use

```
sed 's|https://askubuntu.com/questions|https://askubuntu.com/posts|' file
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that at least in GNU sed, `/` can be replaced by an alternate character in contexts other than the `s`(substitute) command - but in that case it needs to be escaped the first time e.g. `sed '/foo/d'` (delete lines matching `foo`) becomes `sed '\#foo#d'`

Comment: @steeldriver indeed! - I saw that Ravexina added that to his answer, so I shall perhaps leave mine :)

Comment: It isn't important whether the stream contains the separator character. What is important is whether the search string or replacement string contain the separator character.

Comment: @kasperd oh yes, true. I edited slightly :)

Comment: @Zanna's answer is more to the point: The first character after the command "s" determines the separator which is used in this command. You could use *any* character here. `sbabeb` does the same as `s/a/e/`.

Comment: @rexkogitans did you mean Ravexina's answer, or to comment on that answer?

Comment: @Zanna I am surprised that Ravexina's answer is accepted although your answer hits the point more precisely.

Comment: @rexkogitans Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked ;) [Askubuntu Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour).